# Calling bind event outside of function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using a jQuery datepicker plugin from [KelvinLuck](http://2008.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiple.html). It is very simple and straightforward, but I'd like to bind it for any changes and display the date in console. The function is there, but it only works inside the function that initializes the datePicker. I'd like to use the bind function outside of that function. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0muv4zr/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="date-pick"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $('.date-pick')
    .datePicker({
      createButton: false,
      displayClose: false,
      closeOnSelect: true,
      selectMultiple: true,
      inline: true,
      startDate: '01/01/2005',
      endDate: '31/12/2011'
    })
    .dpSetSelected(
      '18/06/2011'
    )
    .bind(
      'click',
      function() {
        $(this).dpDisplay();
        this.blur();
        return false;
      }
    )
    .bind(
      'dateSelected',
      function(e, selectedDate, $td, state) {
        console.log('You ' + (state ? '' : 'un') // wrap
          + 'selected ' + selectedDate);

      }
    )
});
```

The current code displays the date into the console successfully, but I want that bind function outside of the current function. So something like this:

```
$('date-pick').bind(
  'dateSelected',
  function(e, selectedDate, $td, state) {
    console.log('You ' + (state ? '' : 'un') // wrap
      + 'selected ' + selectedDate);

  }
)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: instead of `bind()` use `on()` and chheck

Comment: You are missing a `.` in front of `date-pick`, beside that it would work fine, see this [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0muv4zr/1/). But you should consider not using such an old version of jQuery, and `bind` is deprecated since version 3.0, and since version 1.7 the `on` function is recommended over `bind`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
$(function() {
  $('.date-pick')
    .datePicker({
      createButton: false,
      displayClose: false,
      closeOnSelect: true,
      selectMultiple: true,
      inline: true,
      startDate: '01/01/2005',
      endDate: '31/12/2011'
    });
    // Your binding event functions have been removed from here. Its declared outside this function.
});
$('.date-pick').bind(    // You did not put `.` here
  'dateSelected',
  function(e, selectedDate, $td, state) {
    console.log('You ' + (state ? '' : 'un') // wrap
      + 'selected ' + selectedDate);

  }
);
```

Comment: An _"answer"_  then only contains `Here is your solution:` without explaining what you have changed and why it should work with your changes, is not really helpful. And if it is just an typo then it should be a comment and the question should be closed.

Comment: Sorry @t.niese. Let me update my answer with comments.

Comment: Is it fine now? If it was helpful then can I have an up vote and can it be accepted ?
Thank you so much in advance. Happy to help.